# Would like some more information on React Native version of require

Tags: react-native

As you can see in this part of the React Native codebase https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/ReactNative/ReactNative.js Facebook seem to be using their own version of require. (if you look at the first require line: 
`require('ReactChildren')`) you see this doesn't follow any standard, as there isn't a NPM module called ReactChildren. Would someone be able to explain what they do to help me understand how it works? Pointing to some code or documentation would be amazing.

It seems strange to me that they'd create their own version of require, so any thinking behind why they did this would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the packager they have build to compile the assets. [This is likely the area where you will find more detail on this topic.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/82000416948edaf9431f94bdfc4db30e5fea529c/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. Seems the comment `@providesModule SomeBundleName` on top of the file allows a `require('SomeBundleName')` to get the correct module (as you can see react-native is full of them: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?p=1&q=providesModule&utf8=%E2%9C%93) looks like it's a feature of `node-haste` which is used in react-native.