# Compiling React Native source for testing with Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, react-native, mocha.js

With the recent change in React Native v0.25.0 and 0.26.0 to separate out React and React Native, I've started experiencing an issue where my unit tests using Mocha will no longer run, failing as my test init script tries to compile the React Native source down from ES6. My unit tests had previously been working fine with a combo of `babel-register` and ignoring/including certain parts of `node_modules/` (see [my basic test init script setup](https://gist.github.com/jlyman/09d42c856903abd48948daa9ed64c617)).

Specifically, the init script fails with `Error: Cannot find module 'ReactNative'` when parsing `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js`. When examining the file, sure enough you find a `require('ReactNative')` line in there; the [result of the commit to fully separate out React/RN](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/2eafcd45dbd42f750df1ab9aa3770fed5cdf11ae#diff-cb910bd1233e7351becdc4aca5ad3688R122). I can understand why Node and babel-register are dying here--that `require` doesn't follow normal conventions but seems to be part of the node-haste system FB has going for the RN project. [This SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482853/would-like-some-more-information-on-react-native-version-of-require) was helpful in learning a bit more about it, but it doesn't look like I'd have any sort of recourse to get my Mocha tests running because I can't involve node-haste in the Babel transpilation in prep for running the tests.

I'll be trying out `react-native-mock` when it becomes compatible with RN v0.26.0, but it would be nice to get back to being able to run my unit tests without it, because I didn't need it previously. Am I missing something in my Mocha stack that would make this magically work? What am I not understanding about the React Native stack that would help me work around this and still unit test my various pieces?

*(Note: I am primarily testing things like API elements, action creators/reducers, and various utility methods, **not** checking rendering output of React components.)*

Comment: what happens when you remove `--compilers js:babel-register`?  since your fixture requires `babel-register`, it looks like it'll get loaded twice with two separate configs.

Comment: also it's worth noting that `--compilers js:babel-register` is (in most cases) functionally equivalent to `--require babel-register`.  there's nothing special about `--compilers` except that you can choose a file extension.

Comment: Great to know @boneskull, thanks. Unfortunately, removing the additional `--compilers` flag doesn't change anything, still getting `Error: Cannot find module 'ReactNative'` when running the tests.